# Remove xml element node based on index

Tags: php, arrays, xml, domdocument

I have an xml file with many elements, I am looking to remove certain elements based on their indexes.

Sample XML:

```
<songs>
   <song>
      <title>A</title>
      <artist>AA</artist>
   </song>
</songs>
```

PHP Code I have so far:

```
<?php

$index = $_GET['song'];

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load("songs.xml");
$songs = $doc->getElementsByTagName("song");

foreach($songs as $song) {
    if(in_array($song[$index], $songs)){
        unset($song);
    }
}
$doc->save("songlist.xml");

?>
```

But I get this error from this code:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type DOMElement as array
```

Any help at all is appreciated in this issue, thank you.

Comment: what are you trying to unset anyway? the whole `<song>`?

Comment: @Ghost yes, I am trying to remove the whole song child of songs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intent is to remove the whole `<song>` element. Use `->removeChild()`:

```
$songs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('song');
$hated_artists = array('AA', 'BB', 'CC');
foreach($songs as $song) {
    $artist = $song->getElementsByTagName('artist')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    if(in_array($artist, $hated_artists)) { // if this song is sang by one of your hated artists
        $song->parentNode->removeChild($song); // remove this song
    }
}
```

[Sample Usage](http://codepad.viper-7.com/VaER0H)

If you just want a simple criteria, removing by your desired key, then just use the `foreach` key. Example:

```
$keys_to_be_removed = array(14, 18);
foreach($songs as $key => $song) {
    if(in_array($key, $keys_to_be_removed)) {
        $song->parentNode->removeChild($song);
    }
}
```

Or just explicitly using indexing to delete without the foreach loop:

```
// starts at index zero
$first_song = $doc->getElementsByTagName('song')->item(0);
$songs = $doc->documentElement;
$songs->removeChild($first_song);
```

Comment: thanks for the tip about the ->removeChild(). But I'm not trying to remove my hated artists. Imagine there are 30 song elements in the songs root element. I just want to remove one of them based on the index. for example songs[14], songs[8], ect. How do I do this?

Comment: @SunnyD oh okay, just use the foreach key. remember though, this is starts from zero, so the first song will land on index zero. check my edit. i thought you wanted to delete your hated songs/artists, lol

Comment: @SunnyD i added another piece of info on my revision also, okay, i thought that was your criteria of removing :D, anyways im glad this helped

Answer (score 0):

```
$songs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('song');

$songs.item(1).parentNode.removeChild($songs.item(1));
$songs.item(7).parentNode.removeChild($songs.item(7));
$songs.item(12).parentNode.removeChild($songs.item(12));
```

etc...

Comment: I tried this too but while it got rid of the error, its not deleting  the element from the xml file...

Answer (score 0):

XPath can select nodes by their index/position (it starts with 1). It will always return a node list that is traversable with foreach. The list will be empty if the index does not exists. To delete a node from the DOM you have to remove it from its parent node.

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<songs>
   <song>
      <title>A</title>
      <artist>AA</artist>
   </song>
</songs>
XML;

$index = 1; // (int)$_GET['song'];

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//song['.$index.']') as $song) {
  $song->parentNode->removeChild($song);
}

echo $doc->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<songs>

</songs>
```